# How can I show a checkbox only at the root item of a QTreeView?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have code which reads an XML doc and displays it into Treeview; now I want to add checkboxes at the root.

I am using QT community version. I am able to read the XML file and display data in the Tree but the checkbox is not working and I need checkbox at root only.

DomItem.cpp

```
#include "DOMItem.h"
#include<QCheckBox>
#include <QtXml>

//! [0]
DomItem::DomItem(const QDomNode &node, int row, DomItem *parent)
    : domNode(node),
//! [0]
      // Record the item's location within its parent.
//! [1]
      parentItem(parent),
      rowNumber(row)
{}
//! [1]

//! [2]
DomItem::~DomItem()
{
    qDeleteAll(childItems);
}
//! [2]

//! [3]
QDomNode DomItem::node() const
{
    return domNode;
}
//! [3]

//! [4]
DomItem *DomItem::parent()
{
    return parentItem;
}
//! [4]

//! [5]
DomItem *DomItem::child(int i)
{
    DomItem *childItem = childItems.value(i);
    if (childItem)
        return childItem;

    // if child does not yet exist, create it
    if (i >= 0 && i < domNode.childNodes().count()) {
        QDomNode childNode = domNode.childNodes().item(i);
        childItem = new DomItem(childNode, i, this);
        childItems[i] = childItem;
    }
    return childItem;
}
//! [5]

//! [6]
int DomItem::row() const
{
    return rowNumber;
}
//! [6]
QVariant DomItem::data(int column) const
{
    return itemData.value(column);
}
```

DomModel.cpp

```
#include "DomModel.h"
#include "DOMItem.h"
//#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QtXml>
#include<QCheckBox>

//! [0]
DomModel::DomModel(const QDomDocument &document, QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractItemModel(parent),
      domDocument(document),
      rootItem(new DomItem(domDocument, 0))
{
}
//! [0]

//! [1]
DomModel::~DomModel()
{
    delete rootItem;
}
//! [1]

//! [2]
int DomModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return 3;
}
//! [2]

/*/! [3]
QVariant DomModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
        return QVariant();

    const DomItem *item = static_cast<DomItem*>(index.internalPointer());

    const QDomNode node = item->node();
//! [3] //! [4]

    switch (index.column()) {
        case 0:
            return node.nodeName();
        case 1:
        {
            const QDomNamedNodeMap attributeMap = node.attributes();
            QStringList attributes;
            for (int i = 0; i < attributeMap.count(); ++i) {
                QDomNode attribute = attributeMap.item(i);
                attributes << attribute.nodeName() + "=\""
                              + attribute.nodeValue() + '"';
            }
            return attributes.join(' ');
        }
        case 2:
            return node.nodeValue().split('\n').join(' ');
        default:
            break;
    }
    return QVariant();
}
//! [4] */

QVariant DomModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    DomItem *item = static_cast<DomItem*>(index.internalPointer());
    const QDomNode node = item->node();


    if ( role == Qt::CheckStateRole && index.column() == 0 )
        return static_cast< int >( item->isChecked() ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked );

    if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
        return QVariant();

    switch (index.column()) {
        case 0:
            return node.nodeName();
        case 1:
        {
            const QDomNamedNodeMap attributeMap = node.attributes();
            QStringList attributes;
            for (int i = 0; i < attributeMap.count(); ++i) {
                QDomNode attribute = attributeMap.item(i);
                attributes << attribute.nodeName() + "=\""
                              + attribute.nodeValue() + '"';
            }
            return attributes.join(' ');
        }
        case 2:
            return node.nodeValue().split('\n').join(' ');
        default:
            break;
    }
    return item->data(index.column());
}

/*
//! [5]
Qt::ItemFlags DomModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return Qt::NoItemFlags;

    return QAbstractItemModel::flags(index);
}
//! [5]
*/
Qt::ItemFlags DomModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return Qt::NoItemFlags;

    Qt::ItemFlags flags = Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable;

    if ( index.column() == 0 )
        flags |= Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable;

    return flags;
}
//! [6]
QVariant DomModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                              int role) const
{
    if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal && role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
        switch (section) {
            case 0:
                return tr("Name");
            case 1:
                return tr("Attributes");
            case 2:
                return tr("Value");
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return QVariant();
}
//! [6]

//! [7]
QModelIndex DomModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (!hasIndex(row, column, parent))
        return QModelIndex();

    DomItem *parentItem;

    if (!parent.isValid())
        parentItem = rootItem;
    else
        parentItem = static_cast<DomItem*>(parent.internalPointer());
//! [7]

//! [8]
    DomItem *childItem = parentItem->child(row);
    if (childItem)
        return createIndex(row, column, childItem);
    return QModelIndex();
}
//! [8]

//! [9]
QModelIndex DomModel::parent(const QModelIndex &child) const
{
    if (!child.isValid())
        return QModelIndex();

    DomItem *childItem = static_cast<DomItem*>(child.internalPointer());
    DomItem *parentItem = childItem->parent();

    if (!parentItem || parentItem == rootItem)
        return QModelIndex();

    return createIndex(parentItem->row(), 0, parentItem);
}
//! [9]

//! [10]
int DomModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (parent.column() > 0)
        return 0;

    DomItem *parentItem;

    if (!parent.isValid())
        parentItem = rootItem;
    else
        parentItem = static_cast<DomItem*>(parent.internalPointer());

    return parentItem->node().childNodes().count();
}
//! [10]
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include "DomModel.h"

#include <QDomDocument>
#include <QTreeView>
#include <QMenuBar>
#include <QFileDialog>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent),
      model(new DomModel(QDomDocument(), this)),
      view(new QTreeView(this))
{
    fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File"));
    fileMenu->addAction(tr("&Open..."), this, &MainWindow::openFile, QKeySequence::Open);
    fileMenu->addAction(tr("E&xit"), this, &QWidget::close, QKeySequence::Quit);

    view->setModel(model);

    setCentralWidget(view);
    setWindowTitle(tr("QTreeViewXML"));
    setWindowIcon(QIcon("C:\\Users\arpit.k\\Documents\\QT\\build-QTreeViewXML-Desktop_Qt_6_2_4_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\\Accordlogo.png"));
}

void MainWindow::openFile()
{
    QString filePath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"),
        xmlPath, tr("XML files (*.xml);;HTML files (*.html);;"
                    "SVG files (*.svg);;User Interface files (*.ui)"));

    if (!filePath.isEmpty()) {
        QFile file(filePath);
        if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
            QDomDocument document;
            if (document.setContent(&file)) {
                DomModel *newModel = new DomModel(document, this);
                view->setModel(newModel);
                delete model;
                model = newModel;
                xmlPath = filePath;
            }
            file.close();
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow window;
    window.resize(640, 480);
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: "Please Help me! my job depends on solving this!" - That is completely irrelevant to us and StackOverflow and stuff like that doesn't belong in a question.

Answer (score 0):

In `DomModel::flags()` try using this:

```
if ( index.column() == 0 && !index.parent().isValid() )
        flags |= Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable;
```

because `!index.parent().isValid()` returns `true` only for the root.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but, it didn't worked :'(

Comment: Actually it worked but with little placement at different function.

Comment: in domData(){if ( role == Qt::CheckStateRole && !index.parent().isValid())